# Spring Boot 2, Angular 8 - problem to communicate with /oauth/token from front-end

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I found a tutorial in the Internet which is about Spring Boot 2 and oauth2, from which I haven been learning. This tutorial involves the backend side, authenticating users using database. It works ok when I use Postman to test it. The problem is to communiate front-end with this backend.

The below details from the tutorial from which I have been learning from:

When I try to login from Angular:

login.component.html

```
onSubmit() {
if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
  return;
}
const body = new HttpParams()
  .set('username', this.loginForm.controls.username.value)
  .set('password', this.loginForm.controls.password.value)
  .set('grant_type', 'password');

this.info.login(body.toString()).subscribe(data => {

     }
)
```

service.ts

```
login(loginPayload) {

const headers = {

  'grant_type':'password',
  'username':'user',
  'password':'pass'
}

return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:9191/' + 'oauth/token', loginPayload, {headers});

}
```

there is no communication from the backend side, nothing happens. There was earlier problem with the CORS configuration, but I fixed this. The only communication which I've got now with the backend is from the level of Postman - I type the password, receive the token and I've got the access.

what is not right with it?

Details from the [tutorial](https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube/tree/master/video_009-authorization-server-with-mysql).

I added to this CORSFilter into config package:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

public CORSFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, 
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  //  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, x-auth-token, origin, content-type, accept");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, x-auth-token, username, grant_type, password, origin, content-type, accept");


    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
}
```

Postman:

```
http://localhost:9191/oauth/token

grant_type:password,
username:suranga,
password:spass
```

the above returns generated token

```
{
    "access_token": "1bd8465d-d1a8-428f-8366-a3d4fd2909d7",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "692dfd38-e8dc-4333-8e64-9c0ee78fd5a9",
    "expires_in": 3514,
    "scope": "READ WRITE"
}
```

and using the above generated token:

```
http://localhost:9191/oauth/check_token?token=1bd8465d-d1a8-428f-8366-a3d4fd2909d7
```

with the basic Auth:

```
username: Mobile
password: pin
```

I get access to this information:

```
{
    "aud": [
        "inventory",
        "payment"
    ],
    "user_name": "suranga",
    "scope": [
        "READ",
        "WRITE"
    ],
    "active": true,
    "exp": 1583590024,
    "authorities": [
        "update_profile",
        "ROLE_operator",
        "read_profile"
    ],
    "client_id": "mobile"
}
```

Comment: Please could you share more details of backend implementation, and also successful request with postman, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Thierry Falvo, but I've got all the time http://localhost:9191/oauth/token 401

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of details about your backend server implementation.

Could you check and try this below please. Open Chrome Developer Tools and check Network tab to follow HTTP POST request executed.

oauth-response.model.ts

```js
export interface OAuthResponse {
  access_token: string,
  refresh_token: string,
  scope: string,
  token_type: string
}
```

oauth.service.ts

```js
const clientId: 'my-client-id'; // should come from environment.ts file
const secret: 'my-secret';  // should come from environment.ts file 

...

login(username: string, password: string): Observable<OAuthResponse> {
  let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('username', username)
    .set('password', password)
    .set('grant_type', 'password');

  return this.httpClient.post<OAuthResponse>('http://localhost:9191/oauth/token', params.toString(), {
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
      'Authorization': `Basic ${clientId}:${secret}`
    }
  });
}
```

login.component.ts

```js
onSubmit() {
  ...
  const username = this.loginForm.value['username'];
  const password = this.loginForm.value['password'];

  this.oauthService.login(username, password).subscribe(response => {
    const accessToken = response.access_token;
  });
)
```